# Как получить создателя, дату создания и id сервера?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

Создаю своего бота в дс.

1. Как получить создателя сервера.
2. Как получить дату создания сервера.
3. Как получить ID сервера.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Я нашёл решение моего вопроса в данном видео.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pHPomZOafmo&t

```
{ name: 'Название сервера', value: message.guild.name },
        { name: 'Владелец сервера', value: `${message.guild.owner}(${message.guild.ownerID})` },
        { name: 'Сервер создан', value: message.guild.createdAt },
        { name: 'Колличество участников', value: players},
        { name: 'В сети', value: mess.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'online').size},
        { name: 'Не в сети', value: mess.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'offline').size},
        { name: 'Не беспокоить', value: mess.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'DND').size},
        { name: 'Не активен', value: mess.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.presence.status === 'idle').size},
        { name: 'Колличество ботов', value: mess.guild.members.cache.filter(member => member.user.bot).size },
        { name: 'Регион', value: message.guild.region},
```

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 1):

Получение информации о сервере - https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#get-guild
Возвращаемые данные - https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#guild-object

- id - ID сервера
- owner_id - создатель сервера

Дата создания сервера здесь, на сколько я понимаю, не возвращается, но сам ID сервера можно конвертировать в дату создания с помощью данного кода (https://github.com/hugonun/discordid2date)

```
function convertIDtoUnix(id) {
        /* Note: id has to be str */
        var bin = (+id).toString(2);
        var unixbin = '';
        var unix = '';
        var m = 64 - bin.length;
        unixbin = bin.substring(0, 42-m);
        unix = parseInt(unixbin, 2) + 1420070400000;
        return unix;
    }

    function convert(id) {
        var unix = convertIDtoUnix(id.toString());
        var timestamp = moment.unix(unix/1000);
        document.getElementById('i-date24').innerHTML = timestamp.format('YYYY-MM-DD, HH:mm:ss');
        document.getElementById('i-date12').innerHTML = timestamp.format('YYYY-MM-DD, h:mm:ss A');
        document.getElementById('i-timezone').innerHTML = moment.tz.guess();
        document.getElementById('i-timeago').innerHTML = timestamp.fromNow();
        document.getElementById('i-timestamp').innerHTML = unix;
    }
```

Если вы используете Discord.js для создания бота, то стоит посмотреть это здесь https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild

Comment: .что-то я не могу понять. У меня все пишет undefined. Я явно что-то делаю не так.{ name: 'ID Сервера', value: guild.ID }

Comment: @ДимаБелич, что за name и value? Где вы это взяли? Можете показать код, с помощью которого вы пытаетесь получить информацию о сервере?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/aU0Gfyvq